# Time and space complexity of function that calls another function nested inside

Tags: big-o

```
def square(n):
    def same_number(n):
        if n == 0 :
            return 0
        else :
            return 1 + same_numer(n - 1)
    return n * same_number(n)
```

To my understanding the time complexity and space complexity of same_number are both O(n). However what is the time and space complexity of square which calls same_number? Is it just 1 or do you have to account for same_number?

Comment: Any feedback on the received answer?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q:** To my understanding the time complexity and space complexity of
>   same_number are both O(n).

Correct. This function is recursively called `n` times until it starts to return the result, so it is `O(n)`.

> **Q:** However what is the time and space complexity of square which calls
>   same_number?

It directly depends on the time and space complexity of `same_number`, so `O(n)` again. Function `square` will not finish until `same_number` has finished, so its running time is exactly the running time of `same_number` (it does not add any additional operations).